# Personalised link using checksum tokens leads to empty page

Tags: wordpress, civimail, profile, tokens, checksum

When testing the functionality of checksum tokens for a mailing, the link is properly created according to this [wiki entry](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens) for profile pages (.../?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=**N**&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}). However, clicking the link leads to an empty page that shows the profile title twice, but no other content.

Interesting: When clicking on Wordpress' customize button, the profile including the respective data is shown above the page – although home page instead of the CiviCRM page.

We're on CiviCRM 4.7.8 for Wordpress (Graphy theme) and are trying to set this up for the first time.

What I tried:

- Using a different browser (Firefox and Chrome) and different devices (Windows PC and Android Phone) didn't show any differences.
- I wasn't sure whether a reCAPTCHA would cause problems so I turned it off for this profile, but that didn't help.
- Clearing cache and resetting paths didn't change anything either.
- Not sure if this is relevant, but the sidebar is also shown despite having changed the WP template to "no sidebar".

Any other ideas what could cause this?

Comment: In the URL.../?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}, did you remember to change the letter N to the exact ID of the Profile you want to send the checksum to? You can find the profile Id at Administer>Customize data...>Profiles

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, it should the correct id, because the data is shown if I click customize in the black WP bar at the top of the page. This couldn't be permission-related, could it? However, there is no message regarding permission...

Comment: Just a few more thoughts:
1. In the civicrm menu administer>Customize data..>Profiles>Profile Title>More>Preview, does the preview show the correct fields?
2.  I'm not sure what you mean by the WP bar and customize at the top of the page.  Can you show a screenshot?
3.  Have you tried doing all this with another theme in case the problem is theme related?

Comment: After some tinkering, I found the problem. I sincerely apologise for my stupidity. The link was incorrect. Instead of
.../civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&gid=16&reset=1&gid=16&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}
I used
.../?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=16&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}
Problem is now solved...

Comment: Nice to know you solved it.  Perhaps you could now file your comment as "Your Answer" below so that others will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems only the link was incorrect and lead to the explained behaviour. The wiki entry over at civicrm.org is inaccurate (for Wordpress installations at least). The suggested link is

.../?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=**N**&{con‌​tact.checksum}&id={c‌​ontact.contact_id}

while in my case the correct link is

.../**civicrm**/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&gid=**N**&rese‌​t=1&gid=16&{contact.‌​checksum}&id={contac‌​t.contact_id}

I realised the link was missing the "civicrm" part, when I tested the profile in "create mode", which gave me the correct (second) link. Hopefully, someone else may find this useful.