# CheckSum tokens lead to blank page (2.)

Tags: profile, checksum

I'm brand new to checksums. This problem was reported several years ago. [Personalised link using checksum tokens leads to empty page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/personalised-link-using-checksum-tokens-leads-to-empty-page)  I have the same symptom: the checksum URL points to a page with the name of the profile repeated 10 times but none of the profile fields are displayed. The problem reported several years ago turned out to be a bad URL.  I've checked my URL with the CiviCRM documentation which shows this profile for Wordpress (without clean URLs); [http://example.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&id=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D).  I replaced IDNUMBER with the number of my profile. I tested using the number of an alternate profile with the same result: the URL points to a page with the name of the alternate profile (repeated 10 times) but none of the fields displayed.
CiviCRM 5.48.0 on Wordpress Version 6.0 (without clean URLs)

Comment: might be worth comparing with https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ in case it works as expected on that site which then may point towards some config / path issue specific to yours

Comment: When I use the wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org test facility I can reproduce the error I'm having if I use the profile for Wordpress sites without clean URLs.  But if I use the profile for WP sites with clean URLs the profile displays correctly.
Unfortunately, our museum site operates without clean URLs so I haven't isolated the problem.  (Thanks for the suggestion to try that demo site. I hadn't realized that it could be used for testing as well as demos.)

Comment: Clarifying my earlier comment: our webmaster just advised me thatour Wordpress site has the code enabled for clean URLs but the we haven't done the housekeeping to clean up the URLs.